# Using malloc() in C

Tags: c, file, memory, malloc

**Stars**

---

Given a file named testdata.in, print all the stars in ascending order based on the number of stars
for each line.

**Format Input**

The input contains N line of stars to be sorted.

**Format Output**

Print the stars in ascending order based on the number of stars for each line.

**Constraints**

The number of N lines inside the testdata.in is not specified. However, it is guaranteed that the data will not exceed the given memory limit.

**Sample Input (testdata.in)**

```
**********
****
******
*****
*********
********
*******
************
***********
*
***
**
```

**Sample Output**

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
***********
************
```

**This is the code that I've made. I want to use malloc in this code but I wonder how**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char star[40000][40000], temp[10][40000];

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("testdata.in", "r");
    int count = 0; 
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s\n", &star[count]) == 1) {
        count++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            if (strcmp(star[i], star[j]) < 0) {
                strcpy(temp[0], star[i]);
                strcpy(star[i], star[j]);
                strcpy(star[j], temp[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", star[i]);
    }
    count = 0;
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to *implement* `malloc`? I suspect you want to *use* `malloc`.

Comment: I don't think you want to *implement* `malloc()`, you want to *use* it, right? I don't quite see where the assignment requires that; it seems that you may assume that the data does not exceed whatever statically reserved memory you have. -- Sidenote: For reading complete lines, [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: As on how to use malloc, what exactly does [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) leave unanswered?

Comment: @KeithThompson my bad, i wanna use malloc

Comment: @DevSolar yes i want to use malloc

Comment: A different approach: read the stars one at a time using `fgetc()`, counting the number of stars on each line. Then store the **number** of stars in a one-dimensional array. Sort the array of numbers. Then generate the output. For example, if the sorted array is {3,5}, then output a line with 3 stars, followed by a line with 5 stars. Note that you'll still want to allocate memory with `malloc`, and when the array fills up, use `realloc` to make it bigger.

Comment: This is an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Saying that you want to use malloc for this is like asking how to use a dishwasher for chopping wood or a coffee machine to play music.

Comment: @klutt: So many questions are answered in video: [Is the Dishwasher OK for Cutting Boards?](https://recipes.howstuffworks.com/tools-and-techniques/cleaning-your-cooking-area/how-to-maintain-a-clean-cutting-board2.htm), [The Hard Core Coffee Machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5OYQOyceoM) or the more elaborate [Coffee Machine Music by Jura](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YP97NpeWfZ0)

Comment: @klutt lol i'm just curious mate

Answer (score 1):

why bothering on storing the lines? the whole text is stars, so the easiest way would be saving some sort of histogram: The number of 1-star-lines, the number of 2-star-lines, ...

so essentially an array

```
#define MAX_STARS_PER_LINE 40000
uint32_t counts[MAX_STARS_PER_LINE+1] = {0};

/* pseudocode:
  while not eof:
    line = getline  (without line ending character)
    stars = length(line)
    counts[stars]++;
 */
```

After reading the file just go through this array and for each entry `i` print `counts[i]` lines of `i` stars.

Of course you could do it the other way around, keeping an array with an entry for each line, but a single number for each line is enough. Then of course you have to sort the array